# update javascript object`s method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this declaration:

```
$scope.showAlert = function() {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Notification',
        template: ''
    );
    $timeout(function() {
        alertPopup.close(); //close the popup after 3 seconds for some reason
                }, 30000);
};
```

then I have this:

```
      if (!$scope.newDevice.name) {
            $scope.showAlert.template = 'Name Required';
            showAlert();
            return;
        }
```

But I don't know exactly how to update `template` after I`ve declared it empty.
I have tried:

```
$scope.showAlert.template = 'Name Required';
```

or `$scope.showAlert['template'] = 'Name Required';`  but couldn't`t make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `template` is just a property of an object. The scope of this object is the function `showAlert`, so you cannot access it and update it from outside the method. What you can do instead is to introduce template parameter to function `showAlert`, and use it when displaying alert:

```
$scope.showAlert = function(alertTemplate) {  // <- introduce parameter
    if(alertTemplate === undefined) {   // If parameter was not provided ...
        alertTemplate = '';             // ... set it to empty string
    }
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Notification',
        template: alertTemplate    // <- use parameter value
    );
    $timeout(function() {
        alertPopup.close(); //close the popup after 3 seconds for some reason
                }, 30000);
};
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
if (!$scope.newDevice.name) {
    $scope.showAlert('Name Required');
    return;
}
```

In cases where you don't need to provide custom template, you can simply omit the parameter, and empty string will be used:

```
$scope.showAlert();
```

Comment: if I add $scope.showAlert('anything');  it will pop-out 2 times this allert. once without and once with the Template

Comment: I have to add it showAlert('anything');   but this doesnt pass the param

Comment: @Xao You're not showing some code. If you call `showAlert()` like you did in your sample it should throw an error, because function `showAlert` does not exist (or at least you are not showing it). And if no other alert function exists on `$scope` I don't see a reason why popup should be shown twice.